# Laravel 8 returns blank page

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, laravel-routing

***Laravel is run when İ write this route.***

```
    Route::get('/', 'merchantController@pricedefinition');
```

***But if i write any name like this***

```
     Route::get('/ps', 'merchantController@pricedefinition');
```

***returns blank page.
What is the porblem ?***

Comment: It's hard to know what's happening without some additional details. Can you enable debugging within your app and run it again please? To do this, navigate to your `config/app.php` file and set `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)`. Then re-run the app. Also, could you post the body of the `pricedefinition` method into your question please? It would help to know what that function is doing (or not doing).

Comment: More information is required to detect the problem. But are you sure you haven't defined any routes in the above lines (especially with wildcards) that might be hit first.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8, you can not use `controller@method` anymore.
Just do it like this:

```
Route::get('/',[YourController::class,'method_here']);
```

You have to read this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8, you should define routes that link to controllers like so:

`Route::get('/ps', [App\Http\Controllers\merchantController::class, 'pricedefinition']);`

Comment: Even so this should throw a MethodNotFound exception